# Finding all $f:[0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ differentiable and convex with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)\cdot f\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=x$

Tags: derivatives, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f:[0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$, differentiable and convex, such that
> $$f(0)=0 \tag1\label1$$
> and
> $$ \ f'(x)\cdot f\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=x, \forall x \tag2\label2$$

---

Obviously, $f(x)=x$ is a solution, so I'm trying to find other solutions.

From \eqref{2} we get $f(x) \gt 0, \ f'(x) \gt 0, \forall x \gt 0$ and $f'(0)=0$ therefore $f$ is strictly increasing.

So far, I don't know how to use the convexity of $f$, the definition of convexity doesn't seem to help.

###### UPDATE:

From \eqref{2} $f'(x)=\dfrac x{f\bigl(f(x)\bigr)}, \ \forall x \gt 0$ therefore $f$ is twice differentiable on $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: try to integrate both sides from $0 \to t$, $t\in(0,\infty) $

Comment: @mwomath To integrate what?

Comment: This could be useful \begin{align}
 \int_0^t {f'\left( x \right)f\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right)dx}  &= \frac{1}{2}t^2   \end{align} 
Substitute $u = f\left( x \right) \Rightarrow du = f'\left( x \right)dx$, then
  \begin{align}\int_0^{f\left( t \right)} {f\left( u \right)du}  = \frac{1}{2}t^2   \end{align}

Comment: clearly, the solution is only the identity function

Comment: @mwomath It's definitely a step forward, still I don't know how to link this to convexity

Comment: I don't know if this help. There is a function regarding  Orlicz space. If $f$ is convex, positive and continuous, and $f(0)=0$, then $f$ is called $f$ Orlicz function. Moreover, if $f$ is Orlicz function then so is $F(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x{f(t)dt}$.

Comment: Sure: $f$ is convex iff $f'$ is increasing (but this needs $f$ twice differentiable)

Comment: @mwomath Actually $f$ is  twice differentiable from (2), for $x \gt 0$. You just gave me a clue, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only function that is convex, has $f(0)=0$ and satisfy $f'(x)f(f(x)) = x$ is the identity $f(x) = x$.

---

Since $f$ is [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition) and $f(0) = 0$ we have $$f(xt) = f(0\cdot (1-t) + x\cdot t) \leq (1-t)f(0) + t f(x) = tf(x) \implies \frac{f(xt)}{xt} \leq \frac{f(x)}{x}$$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. This shows that $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is an increasing function.

We now either have $g(x) < 1$ for all $x$, $g(x) > 1$ for all $x$ or there exist a $x_0$ such that $g(x_0) = 1$. If $g(x) < 1$ for all $x$ we define $x_0 = \infty$ and if $g(x) > 1$ for all $x$ we define $x_0 = 0$.

---

On $[0,x_0)$ we have $f(x) \leq x$  so

$$g(f(x)) \leq g(x) \implies f(f(x)) \leq \frac{f^2(x)}{x}$$ and the functional equation gives $$x \leq f'(x) \frac{f^2(x)}{x} \implies 0 \leq \frac{d}{dx}[f^3(x) - x^3] \implies x \leq f(x)$$ and since $f(x) \leq x$ and $x\leq f(x)$ we have $f(x) = x$ on $[0,x_0)$.

---

On $(x_0,\infty)$ we have $f(x) \geq x$ so 
$$g(f(x)) \geq g(x) \implies f(f(x)) \geq \frac{f^2(x)}{x}$$
and the functional equation gives $$x \geq f'(x) \frac{f^2(x)}{x} \implies 0 \geq \frac{d}{dx}[f^3(x) - x^3] \implies x\geq f(x)$$ and again since $f(x)\geq x$ and $f(x) \leq x$ we have $f(x) = x$ on $(x_0,\infty)$. It follows that $f(x) = x$ for all $x$.

---

Some more details on the integration of the inequality above. Since $0 \leq \frac{d}{dx}[f^3(x) - x^3]$ on $[0,x_0)$ we have
$$0 =\int_0^x 0{\rm d}x \leq \int_0^x \frac{d}{dx}[f^3(x)-x^3)]{\rm d}x = f^3(x) - f^3(0) - x^3 + 0^3 = f^3(x) - x^3 \\\implies x^3 \leq f^3(x) \implies x \leq f(x)$$
for $0\leq x < x_0$ and since $0 \geq \frac{d}{dx}[f^3(x) - x^3]$ on $(x_0,\infty$) we have
$$ 0 =\int_{x_0}^x 0{\rm d}x \geq \int_{x_0}^x \frac{d}{dx}[f^3(x)-x^3)]{\rm d}x = f^3(x) - f^3(x_0) - x^3 + x_0^3 = f^3(x) - x^3\\f^3(x) \leq x^3 \implies f(x) \leq x$$ 
for $x_0 < x$ where we have used $f(x_0) = x_0$ to simplify.

Comment: What if there is no $x_0$ so that $g(x_0) = x_0$?

Comment: @EugenCovaci That is no problem. Then $g(x) < 1$ or $g(x) > 1$ for all $x$ so you can take $x_0 = \infty$ in the first case and $x_0 = 0$ in the second case, i.e. you can skip one of the cases.

Comment: How do you prove $\frac{f(y)}{y} \leq \frac{f(x)}{x}$? This is not true for any convex positive function

Comment: @EugenCovaci It is true since $f(0) = 0$. We have $f((1-t)a + tb) \leq (1-t)f(a) + t f(b)$ for $t\in[0,1]$. Take $a=0$, $b=x$ and $y = tx$ and use $f(0) = 0$ to get $f(y) \leq \frac{y}{x}f(x)$. Since $t\leq 1$ we have $y\leq x$.

Comment: Take $f(x)= \frac 1 x$ The inegality $\frac{f(y)}{y} \leq \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is false for $y \le x$

Comment: @EugenCovaci That function does not have $f(0) = 0$. I gave a proof in the comment above from the definition of convexity.